# -1 or +1 in array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

Hi i hope to get better understanding about those -1, +1 for rows and columns in dynamic ARRAY in old code review post. Thanks: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187246/reorder-columns-in-array?newreg=8d1332e7926d4c61a0cf42c8679faf66

and the codes I tried to use in my current project is Raystafarian's https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/187355/244239,
I know that original post seems has a blank column 8 for the output. 
but mine is simpler, (IN 9 column to OUT 9 column), still I had some issue when I tried to use.

My project: copy a 9-column sheet (without header) into array
then re-order the array then load the data into A2 of existing sheet which has its header row in row 1 (as header label are different from original ).
When I initially use the codes, it wiped my existing header row and it did not include column one or two ending rows from the array. and there is one extra blank row in row2....Then 
(1) I had to change the -1 to be +1 in ReDim newArray(UBound(inputArray, 1) - 1, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)  ;
(2) I had to change newArray(rowIndex - 1, columnIndex - 1) = inputArray(rowIndex - 1, oldColumn(columnIndex - 1)) to be:
newArray(rowIndex, columnIndex) = inputArray(rowIndex - 1, oldColumn(columnIndex - 1))

after tweeking quite a few times it seem correct based on current data file....but I hope to understanding those -1 +1, so that I can be sure, outcome will be correct when I pass onto the user? - really appreciate if you could help me

below are the codes in my project:

```
Dim lastRow As Long    
lastRow = GetLast(openSh, True)    
Dim lastColumn As Long    
lastColumn = GetLast(openSh, False) 

Dim dataAlert() As Variant 

dataAlert = openSh.Range("A10:I" & lastRow).Value

're-order Array columns 
    Const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS As Long = 9
    Const OLD_COLUMNS As String = "6,1,2,4,5,7,8,9,3"
    
    Dim oldColumnArray As Variant
    oldColumnArray = Split(OLD_COLUMNS, ",")
    Dim oldColumn(NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS) As Long
    Dim arrayIndex As Long
    For arrayIndex = LBound(oldColumnArray) To UBound(oldColumnArray)
        oldColumn(arrayIndex) = CInt(oldColumnArray(arrayIndex))
    Next
   

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim columnIndex As Long
  
    Dim newArray As Variant
    ReDim newArray(UBound(dataAlert, 1) + 1, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)

    For arrayIndex = LBound(dataAlert, 2) To UBound(dataAlert, 2)
        For rowIndex = 1 To lastRow
            For columnIndex = 1 To NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS + 1
                newArray(rowIndex - 1, columnIndex) = dataAlert(rowIndex - 1, oldColumn(columnIndex - 1)) 
            Next
        Next
    Next


' Read through the data, load into tgtSh
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim row As Long
    row = 1
    For i = LBound(newArray) + 1 To UBound(newArray) + 1
        
             
            ' Copy each column
            For j = LBound(newArray, 2) To UBound(newArray, 2)
                tgtSh.Cells(row, j).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = newArray(i, j)
            Next j
            
            ' move to the next output row
        row = row + 1
           
    Next i
```

Comment: actually, after i removed On Error Resume Next, it came up Run-time error "9", subscript out of range at "for columnIndex = 1 to NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS +1, newArray(....) = dataAlert(....)"...

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Just to start with - When we redim array, we can change the last dimension only. Also, if you want to rearrange columns in an array and populate a worksheet with it then say for column 2 you can use `Application.Index(array, , 2)` ... You don't have to loop through each cell.

Comment: thanks Naresh, I am not sure how/whether to redeem the dataAlert (the original array which copied the whole sheet from source except header)??
I actually ended up just use recorded cut insert codes....I feel the Application.Index() is a bit hard to deal with the headers labels mostly different in existing sheet from the original array for the same column of data. i did not want to manually change column labels after using applicatin.index

Comment: Also, you can directly assign values from one range to another. Say you want Range F2:F10 from "Source"  sheet 
to Range A2:A10 in target sheet then you can use `Sheets("Target").Range("A2:A10") = Sheets("Source").Range("F2:F10")` you can make it dynamic with `range(cells(row,col),cells(row,col))`

Comment: @Naresh, per your suggestion, will it be much slower if large data and more columns? but i only need change column orders...and row -1...